# css colorbox z-index being ignored (only on Safari Mac)

Tags: css, safari

I have a problem with this site:
https://www.fairtragen.de/product_info.php?products_id=55765

When I click on one of the product images, the grey background layer (div id = "cboxOverlay") is displayed on top of the photo (div id = "colorbox").

[here you can see what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UPJf.png)

The problem only occurs on MacOS with Browser Safari. (reproducable with MacOS 10.12.6 and 10.9.5).
With Firefox and Chrome on Linux and Windows everything runs fine.

These divs are defined in colorbox.css, both with z-index: 9999.
I have changed the colorbox.css in order to assign z-index 9998 to "cboxOverlay". But this did not help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like a rendering bug caused by the browser, it takes issue with the leaves, just remove the 3d rotation on the leaves

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I had these two lines for the rotation:
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,25deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,25deg);
If I only delete the first one, it still works, and also rotates :-)